# Jenkins defaults to https on Firefox and Chrome but not IE

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins was working fine on Firefox until a couple of weeks back.

```
http://www.sub.domain.com:8080
```

Then I think there was a Firefox update and by default it was redirecting to

```
https://www.sub.domain.com:8080
```

There was no way I could force it to http.

So I went on Chrome and it worked there until this morning when I got the Chrome 77 update.

Same issue all over again.

Then I loaded it up on IE. It works fine. I am able to use

```
http://www.sub.domain.com:8080
```

I checked with the admin if they are redirecting all traffic to https but that's not the case. What's happening here? Any browser change that I am not aware of? Any Jenkins config change that I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the HSTS cache in chrome? Go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Query the HSTS cache there.  If there is a result you can clear it using the delete option on that page.

Another thing to check is if your using the Jenkins HSTS filter plugin "which adds a response header indicating that HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) response headers should be sent."  See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HSTS+Filter+Plugin